# Copy of .wav file has a noise on it

Tags: python-2.7, wav

I have written a method that downloads, byte by byte, *.wav files from SD card and saves it on my computer.

```
... #complex method downloading file_content
content = ''.join((chr(b) for b in file_content))

with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
    file.write(content)
```

After new .wav file is created, there is hearable noise on the copy, which is not present on orginal one.
[audacity compare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCOTg.png)

The strange thing is when i compare content of those 2 files char by char, they are identical. No diffrence is found.

[Lint to .wav files](http://dropcanvas.com/bg02f)

Comment: You should be managing files as bytes, so use "b" flag.

Comment: After changing it like you suggested it works now fine.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i did not open file in binary mode.
After changing

```
with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
```

into

```
with open(file_path, 'wb') as file:
```

removed noises on copy of file.